# Build BITXOR Matrix in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to build the following table in excel:

[image: Table]]

E.g. the table has a header row and column and each cell is BITXORing the value from its respective column and row "headers". I want a formula that I can extend down and right, since I will have a 200x200 matrix for the actual data. How can I use structured references to reference the value from #ThisRow(@Column1) and #ThisColumn(@Row1)?

Comment: can you explain the logic on how a BITXOR matrix works ?

Comment: To obtain the table which looks exactly like you show the data type must be 'text'. It makes the use of bitwise functions too difficult (the formula will be too complex, especially when the number of source bits is dynamic). User-defined function is easier solution, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `$` dollar sign to make structured references. A dollar sign will make a relative reference into a semi-absolute or absolute reference.

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=BITXOR($A2,B$1)
```

Drag down and right.

In this case we made column `A` absolute, so it won't move with dragging the formula, while in the second argument we don't want the referenced row to increase. Hence why we can put a `$` in front of the rownumber.

For those who are interested:

- More information about [BITXOR](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-bitxor-function)
- More information about [absolute vs relative](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9) cell references

Comment: No idea, why I couldn't achieve this on my own. Thank you very much, tried around with the $ signs, and actually know it. Thank you very much.

By the way, for everyone that has the same problem. To work around the formatting: set the cell custom format to "000" and a 0 will show as 000 or a 10 as 010.

Comment: @floyd, you are welcome :)